# Why do we sum the sample variance when shoveling snow?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

My text book has the following question

> A highway department has enough salt to handle a total of 80 inches of
> snowfall. Suppose the daily amount of snow has a mean of 1.5 inches
> and a standard deviation of 0.3 inches. Approximate the probability
> that the salt on hand will suffice for the next 50 days

I looked up the solution as follows but I don't understand some steps

Let $X_i$ be a random variable for snow falling on the $i^{th}$ day.
Given,
$$
E[X_i]=1.5 \;inches
$$
$$
SD[Xi]=0.3 \;inches
$$
Let X be the amount of snow expected in 50 days
$$
 X=\sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i
$$
Then,
$$
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{50} E(X_i)=50(1.5)=75
$$
step 2
$$
Var[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{50} (SD[X_i])^2=50(0.09) = 4.5
$$
By central limit theorem, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(E[X_i],Var[X])$
Using general conversion formula
$$
Z=\frac{X-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}
$$
We have
step 3
$$
P(X\leq 80) =  P\left(\frac{X -75}{\sqrt{4.5}} <  \frac{80 -75}{\sqrt{4.5}}\right)
$$
step 4
$$
\approx P(Z \leq 2.3570) =\phi(2.36) =0.99079
$$

I am wanting to know the following;
Is Poisson involved here?
What is the technical name for X? "The expected value"?
Why do we sum the variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there are no Poisson distributions involved in this problem.

$X$ is the random variable that represents the total amount of snowfall in 50 days.  The expected value is $E[X]$.

You can sum the variances because it is assumed that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{50}$, the amounts of snowfall on each individual day, are all independent.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_(Bienaym%C3%A9_formula)) for a proof of the fact that the variance of a sum of independent random variables is equal to the sum of the individual variances.

Comment: Is it not poisson because amount of snow is not discrete?

Comment: We don't know anything about the distribution of the amount of snow on each individual day, except for its mean and variance.  It _could_ be a Poisson, but there's no reason to assume that it is, and it doesn't matter in the problem anyway because the central limit theorem applies to any starting distribution

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by a starting distribution? As I understand it, CLT needs independent identical distribution

Comment: I mean the distribution of the $X_i$.  The CLT applies to the sum $X_1 + \dots + X_n$ whenever the $X_i$ are iid.  It doesn't matter what specifically the distribution of $X_i$ is.

Comment: I have asked a further question at ~https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857218/how-do-i-read-pab~